# Switch language on front page not working

Tags: magento2, localisation

I have installed a language pack for my magento 2 site.

```
wget https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-swedish-language-pack/raw/master/sv_SE.csv
php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace sv_SE.csv sv_SE
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sv_SE
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The translations are ok! But when I change the language in the upper right corner on the front page nothing happends. The footer links are still in english on front page. BUT if I go to example search everything is translated
, but if I then go back to front page, nothing is translated.

Help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands and check.

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US sv_SE
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a known bug in the last version of Magento 2.

You need to try to deploy static content one by one such as :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sv_SE
```

Ticket related :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7862